# Mikrotik Firewall rule: block all connection except to VPN server

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, firewall, mikrotik-routeros

As the title says I need to block all the connection to mikrotik router from outside except connection to VPN server. Then allow Remote desktop to LAN's system over VPN(either L2TP/IPSec or PPTP) from outside LAN.

What would be the rule in Mikrotik router's Firewall to block all the connection except rdp over vpn?

Addition info:

There is LAN setup in our office and the final gateway is Mikrotik router.
I know how to create VPN server, VPN client in clients system and make rdp from clients system.
I want that external firewall should only let in connections to VPN server
vpn firewall rdp mikrotik

Answer (score 5):

**PPTP uses**

- TCP port 1723
- GRE (protocol ID 47) for tunneling

Accept PPTP in Mikrotik:

```
/ip firewall filter add chain=input action=accept protocol=tcp dst-port=1723
/ip firewall filter add chain=input action=accept protocol=gre
```

**L2TP/IPSec uses**

- TCP port 1701
- UDP port 500 for Security Association (SA) - to negotiate security method (password, certificate, kerberos)
- AH (Protocol ID 50) - Authentication Header
- ESP (Protocol ID 51) - Encapsulated Secure Payload

Accept L2TP/IPSec in Mikrotik:

```
/ip firewall filter add chain=input action=accept protocol=tcp dst-port=1701
/ip firewall filter add chain=input action=accept protocol=udp dst-port=500
/ip firewall filter add chain=input action=accept protocol=ipsec-ah
/ip firewall filter add chain=input action=accept protocol=ipsec-esp
```

**Block all other incoming connection (TCP)**

```
/ip firewall filter add chain=input protocol=tcp action=reject reject-with=tcp-reset
```

You can use `action=drop` instead of `reject`, but according to [Hannes Schmidt](http://diaryproducts.net/about/operating_systems/unix/nmap_port_scanner_iptables_firewall), NMAP can still see the port is open but dropped (filtered) by firewall

Comment: please answer my qyestion

Comment: @MehdiHaghshenas: which question?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/876150/mikrotik-reset-user-manager-counter-after-day-or-week