# Mikrotik – reset user manager counter after day or week

Tags: mikrotik-routeros, rate-limits

I have a `Mikrotik router board` and use `userman radius` for accounting.

I want to set a transfer limit to it's users, but I want that transfer limit to be reset periodically, like every day.

Can I do this in `Mikrotik usermanager` and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution

just add a below script

```
/system scheduler
add interval=1d name=ResetCounterUserManager on-event=\
"/tool user-manager user reset-counters [find]" policy=\
ftp,reboot,read,write,policy,test,password,sniff,sensitive start-date=\
may/22/2012 start-time=00:01:00
```

this scheduler reset counter of all user every day.